# Is it possible to uniquely identify a diamond by the refraction of light through it?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, refraction, diamond

I am kinda new to physics and this question was bugging me lately. Is it possible in any way to uniquely identify a diamond , maybe through how it refracts light? Do you know if there is any research on the topic? Feel free to just link me potential resources.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'uniquely identify a diamond'?

Comment: Mainly a one-to-one function from a diamond to an Id that could be numeric or alphanumerical.

Comment: https://www.leibish.com/why-diamonds-are-like-snowflakes-article-374

Comment: I was hoping for some scientific publication :)

Answer (score 1):

jewelers use a handheld magnifier that can be used as a quick approximate *refractometer* with some practice; they can tell the difference between glass and diamond this way.

Precision refractometers can measure the refractive index accurately enough to identify the composition of transparent materials.

Conversely, if the refractive index of a given type of transparent thin film is known, its thickness can be back-calculated with a device called an *ellipsometer*.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a way to uniquely identify a particular diamond.   Yes, this is commonly done.  Because the facet sizes are slightly different on different cut diamonds, and because every diamond has its own unique imperfections, the pattern of light refracted and scattered by each cut diamond is unique.  Some people have made holograms of the scatter patterns to collect the most information possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot , if you have any references to the holograms of scatter patterns that you could I would greatly appreciate it.